# How can I make a Python shell-like GUI using Tkinter?

Tags: python, shell, user-interface, tkinter

I need to make a program that uses as its interface a shell window, like the one the python IDLE uses, this window has to be made. What widgets can I use to perform this. I've heard that the Python IDLE was made using tkinter, if that`s the case, then what widget did they used.

Pd. I've tried using the 'text' widget, but it doesn't freezes commands that have already been processed. Is there a way to freeze the commands that have already been processed,but keep text entry activated.

Answer (score 0):

You should take a look at `PyQt`.  Specifically the `QTextEdit`.  They also have the `QScintilla` library that does code highlighting and formatting.

If you're not opposed to using other peoples' code, Blur Studio has [open sourced](https://sourceforge.net/projects/blur-dev/) much of their code, and they have a widget that is pretty similar.  Once you install the `blurdev` library, it's at `blurdev.gui.windows.loggerwindow`

Comment: If you need more information on QScintilla, you can check out this source: https://qscintilla.com/